# Google analytics track click event

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I would like to track external click event on my website.
I tried to follow a lot of tutorials but its seems this is never what I want to do.

In the source code there is:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-00000000-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

Is that enough to track the click event?

Then should I write:

```
<a href="myLink" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','partner link', 'Click']);">
    hello
</a>
```

to get event tracking on that link?

Comment: yes, probably.  Have you tried it?

Comment: mind that tracked click events sometimes don't show immediately in your GA admin. Open your dev tools, go to the networks pane and see if any event is sent from the browser after clicking on your target.

Comment: no it doesn't work. I went in GA goals, but there is nothing.
 i tried this one : `<a href=”https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide” onClick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘resource’, ‘outbound link’, ‘https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide’, 1, true]);” target=”_blank”>Google’s Guide to Event Tracking</a>`

but it doesnt work neither. I don't know if im doing wrong in the code or in GA pannel

Comment: Just to be certain, are you using classic GA or Universal Analytics?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have changed the code so it includes your domain and UA number, right?  And in case you were not aware, no GA data will appear right away in the GA normal reports, but should be something in the Real  time reports.  Best though is to use the GA Debugger Chrome extension to see if the GA hit event is sent - you should be able to see it in the console.

Comment: Yes i use the GA number provided by my GA account, i already went i "real time reports". i'll keep digging , thanks